# Recibir matriz de struct como parametro

Tags: c, matriz, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct persona;
struct persona{
    int edad;
    char *nombre;
};

void caca(struct persona *a);

int main(){
    struct persona juan[2][2];
    juan[0][0].edad = 29;
    juan[0][1].edad = 7;
    juan[1][0].edad = 29;
    juan[1][1].edad = 29;
    caca(&juan);

    return 0;
}

void caca(struct persona *a){
    printf("%d", a[0][0].edad);

}
```

Me produce este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al momento de inicializarlo como vector y recibirlo e imprimirlo así sí me deja. Pero cuando lo intento con una matriz entonces me produce este error.

Answer (score 0):

hHola, creo que el problema era que estabas haciendo mal el typedef y también que estabas pasando la variable juan por referencia cuando realmente no hace falta. Y también cuando vas a pasar una matriz a una función, hay que indicarle en la cabecera las dimensiones de la misma.
Un saludo y espero que te ayudara.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct persona{
    int edad;
    char *nombre;
}persona;

void caca(persona a[2][2]);

int main(){
    persona juan[2][2];
    juan[0][0].edad = 29;
    juan[0][1].edad = 7;
    juan[1][0].edad = 29;
    juan[1][1].edad = 29;
    caca(juan);

    return 0;
}

void caca(persona a[2][2]){
    printf("%d", a[0][0].edad);

}
```